# Show YouTube video in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video, youtube-data-api

I know some approaches to show videos from YouTube in WPF with WebBrowser (explained [here](http://blog.tedd.no/2010/06/27/embedding-youtube-in-wpf-webbrowser-control/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF)).
But none of them work, I get an "Vector smash protection is enabled." output in my console.

Is this vector smash some kind of attack like XSS on websites?

I trying to figure out, why none of the approaches work properly, either it's the code or it's the protection.

But why is that so that I can write a script which downloads all the videos from YouTube, but it's not possible to embed them in a WebBrowser control or in a MediaElement in WPF (well, MediaElement only supports local video files afaik).

Does anybody have an idea what other approach I could try if there's one?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this is probably due to the IE emulation mode of the WPF web browser (I think it's stuck on IE7). It's possible to get around this using registry hacks. A good guide is:
http://www.cyotek.com/blog/configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-internet-explorer-webbrowser-control

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i read the article and compared the registry settings with those on my machine. unfortunately most of the registy keys aren't listed. in FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION are two keys, HelpPane.exe (10000) and prevhost.exe (8000).
When creating a static class with the code snippets showing on the site, nothing happens. The project does'nt even work with this snippet and crashes with the code 259 (VS2013)

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a similar issue on my home PC. Reading a little about the current state of this, I would say the wpf browser is probably broken for future windows development, especially since Microsoft is giving up on IE almost all together, and the fact it's such a pain to get it to work. Interestingly, there is a new open-source control that incorporates Google's chromium: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp. The reviews seem to be good, and I think it might be worth taking a look at this?